# Extract any basic math expression from arbitrary text using Python

Tags: python, sympy

Is there any way to leverage libraries like `SymPy` to extract (basic) math expressions from any given paragraph?
(Although I understand that the scope of what a "basic" math expression is, is not well-defined and subjective.)

For example, from a text like the following:

> The equation of ellipse is (x^2/a^2) + (y^2/b^2) = 1, assuming center at the origin.

Is there a way to use any symbolic math libraries to detect (heuristically) the boundaries of math equations (if any) from arbitrary strings? (To return `(x^2/a^2) + (y^2/b^2) = 1` for this example)

Comment: `parse_expr` in https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html may be the most 'powerful' parser.  But even it has limits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but this does not solve my question.

Comment: I believe that you will need to define your own regex to do the job. Note that the borders of an equation can be arbitrary without context, since you may interpret single words as factors. E.g. `hello 2 b = 4 world` may yield equations `2b=4` or `2b=4world` which would both be OK without semantic information and the used notation. Thus, I do not believe it is possible to filter arbitrary equations without further assumptions or specifications.